# Is the ~/.bashrc file user specific when I am connected to a remote system using Secure Shell (SSH)?

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-desktop, bashrc, remote-access

I am doing work on a remote computer using Secure Shell. I would like to add aliases to the ~/.bashrc file, but only if this edit applies to my user only. So the question, as the title states, is whether the ~/.bashrc file is user specific when I am connected to a remote system using Secure Shell (SSH)?

Comment: anything in your home folder (~ is a shortcut for /home/your_username, which is your home folder) is specific to the user whose home folder it's in. So it would be specific to anyone who logs in with your username.

Comment: Specific with regard to what user? Remote user, yes (`~/.bashrc`, from the very pathname, is located in your home folder, so it's user-specific). Local user, no.

Comment: Just to be clear, that means that when I edit the ~/.bashrc file my user is the only one who can see that edit, correct?

Comment: Anybody who has access to the file can **see** its contents. It depends what access rights you set for that file. But I guess you meant the file is **executed** when your user logs in. Each user has their own `.bashrc` file and it executes when that user logs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, `~/.bashrc` file is located within `~` directory, that is, user's home directory on the remote machine (`~` is a shortcut used for user's home directory and usually is equal to `/home/username`). So every user has their own separate `~` directory and their own `.bashrc` file located in that directory. Of course this applies to users on the remote machine. When you login via ssh to the remote machine, the remote machine's OS does not distinguish between **local** users (ie. users on the machine you are connecting **from**). All that matters is user on the remote machine.